# Пошаговая настройка репликации clickhouse через zookeper

Tags: clickhouse

Здравствуйте! Может кто-то мне подсказать как правильно сконфигурировать зуукипер для работы кликхауса через него? Сейчас у меня пока 2 сервера, на которых установлены зукипер и кликхаус, на одном из них есть реальная база, которая работает. Задача сделать еще 2 реплики для отказоустойчивости. Конфиги зукипера сейчас выглядят так:

**zoo.conf**

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=30000
syncLimit=10

maxClientCnxns=2000

maxSessionTimeout=60000000
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/ch-1/data
dataLogDir=/opt/zookeeper/ch-1/logs

clientPort=2181
server.1=server1.ru:2888:3888
server.2=server2.ru:2888:3888

autopurge.snapRetainCount=10
autopurge.purgeInterval=1

preAllocSize=131072

snapCount=3000000

leaderServes=yes

standaloneEnabled=false
dynamicConfigFile=/etc/zookeeper-{{ cluster['name'] }}/conf/zoo.cfg.dynamic
```

**environment**

```
NAME=zookeeper
ZOOCFGDIR=/etc/$NAME/conf

CLASSPATH="$ZOOCFGDIR:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/netty.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-api.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/share/java/zookeeper.jar"

ZOOCFG="$ZOOCFGDIR/zoo.cfg"
ZOO_LOG_DIR=/var/log/$NAME
USER=$NAME
GROUP=$NAME
PIDDIR=/var/run/$NAME
PIDFILE=$PIDDIR/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
ZOOMAIN="org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain"
ZOO_LOG4J_PROP="INFO,ROLLINGFILE"
JMXLOCALONLY=false
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms{{ cluster.get('xms','128M') }} \
      -Xmx{{ cluster.get('xmx','1G') }} \
      -Xloggc:/var/log/$NAME/zookeeper-gc.log \
      -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation \
      -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=16 \
      -XX:GCLogFileSize=16M \
      -verbose:gc \
      -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps \
      -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
      -XX:+PrintGCDetails
      -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution \
      -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime \
      -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime \
      -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics \
      -XX:+UseParNewGC \
      -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
  -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled"
```

**configuration.xls**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
  <zookeeper>
    <node index="1">
      <host>server1.ru</host>
      <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <node index="2">
      <host>server2.ru</host>
      <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <macros>
      <layer>01</layer>
      <shard>01</shard>
      <replica>server1.ru</replica>
    </macros>
  </zookeeper>
</yandex>
```

сам зукипер сервер запускается без ошибок и через клиент я могу к нему подключиться.

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

я пытаюсь создать реплику на втором сервере примерно таким запросом

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(date_full_created, datetime_created, year_created, month_created, date_created, my_id, news_id, title) ENGINE ReplicatedMergeTree( "/clickhouse/tables/2/my_table","{replica}", date_full_created, ( datetime_created, year_created, month_created, date_created, my_id, news_id ), 8192);
```

но ничего не происходит. что еще мне надо сделать, чтобы создалась реплика базы на 2 сервере и происходила синхронная запись в обе базы?

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial по настройке мини-кластера ClickHouse с репликацией: 
https://clickhouse.yandex/tutorial.html

Пример конфигурации ZooKeeper:
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/operations/tips/#zookeeper